# Change Background of Android Camera

Tags: android, android-layout, android-camera, android-permissions

I am new to android .I want to develop an Application which change the background of camera and set as according to your desire.Please give me some suggestion to do develop this application.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [OpenCV SDK for Android](http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html). They have a sample in which they apply color filters to camera preview. Though, if you're new to Android it might be difficult to start up with such a sophisticated task and OpenCV, in itself, may be challenging.

Comment: Please give any other idea because its too hard to do that with OpenCV..Thanks